# My three.js canvas get duplicated when I change my view with router in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, three.js, vue-router

I made a simple three.js application integrated in vue.js. Im using router, it works fine but everytime I open the view with my three.js application the canvas gets duplicated. The three.js canvas wont dissapear when I change my view with router but gets stuck below as in my image:

[image]

In the image I opened the view with the three.js animation two times causing the canvas to appear two times below eachother. It wont get erased.

It works fine as soon as I change it to use another component then my three application. So it might be how it renders and if I shall rewrite my three.js code in some way?

Here is the full repo for download:
https://github.com/reppoper/routerthree

Here is my code:
**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-link to="/">Page1</router-link> | 
    <router-link to="/page2">Page2</router-link> 
     <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
  }
}
</script>
```

**Page1.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <HelloWorld/>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "../components/HelloWorld.vue";
export default {
    components: {
        HelloWorld
    }
}
</script>
```

**Page2.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <HelloThree />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloThree from "../components/HelloThree.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    HelloThree,
  },
};
</script>
```

And my components:
**HelloWorld.vue**

```
    <template>
      <div class="hello">
        <h1>HELLO</h1>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script>
    export default {
      name: 'HelloWorld',
    }
    </script>
```

**HelloThree.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="container"></div>
</template>
<script>

import * as THREE from 'three'

export default {
  name: 'HelloThree',
  data() {
    return {
      cube: null,
      renderer: null,
      scene: null,
      camera: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    init: function() {
      this.scene = new THREE.Scene()
      this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
        75,
        window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
        0.1,
        1000
      )

      this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer()
      this.renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)

     // document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)
      // SOLUTION
      this.container = document.getElementById("container");
      this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);

      const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1)
      const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 })
      this.cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
      this.scene.add(this.cube)

      this.camera.position.z = 5

    },
    animate: function() {
      requestAnimationFrame(this.animate)

      this.cube.rotation.x += 0.01
      this.cube.rotation.y += 0.01

      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera)
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.init()
    this.animate()
  }
}
</script>
```

**router.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Router from "vue-router";
import Page1 from "./views/Page1.vue";
Vue.use(Router);

export default new Router({
    mode: "history",
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/",
            name: "page1",
            component: Page1
        },
        {
            path: "/page2",
            name: "page2",
            component: () =>
                import(/* webpackChunkName: "home" */ "./views/Page2.vue")
        }
    ]
});
```

**UPDATE**
I tried to handle the memory leakage by adding:

```
  beforeDestroy() {
    this.container.destroy();
  },
```

but got errormessage

```
Error in beforeDestroy hook: "TypeError: this.container.destroy is not a function"
```

I guess I need to destroy all instances I created in the component. material, scene, camera etc?

Answer (score 0):

Well in your `HelloThree` component `mounted` hook you are appending new node into the DOM by hand (`document.body.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement)`) so it's your responsibility to remove it when the component is destroyed. Appropriate place would be for example [beforeDestroy](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy) hook

Also check whether THREE library needs some cleanup or you will create [memory leak in your app](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/avoiding-memory-leaks.html)

Comment: I solved this by adding          ` this.container = document.getElementById("container");
          this.container.appendChild(this.renderer.domElement);`  See update above in HelloThree.vue

Comment: However Im not sure how to solve the memory leakage. I tried to add this.container.destroy(); as above but I got errormessage. Error in beforeDestroy hook: "TypeError: this.container.destroy is not a function" see the bottom of my original question. Thanks!